# applying DISTINCT SUM

Tags: sql, oracle, toad

I'm working on a code that would help me get the sum amount of GL Sub Heads (that's an accounting term) in a table. things is, there are multiple rows with the same GL Sub Head but with different amounts. I need to sum up the amounts of the table per GL Sub Head. that of course, involves the use of `SUM` and `DISTINCT` clauses. here's what I have so far:

```
select 
    gstt.bal_date,
    sum(gstt.tot_dr_bal) as totalDr,
    sum(gstt.tot_cr_bal) as totalCr

from( 
    select distinct 
        gam.gl_sub_head_code, 
        gstt.tot_dr_bal,
        gstt.tot_cr_bal

    from tbaadm.gam

    left outer join tbaadm.eab 
        on gam.acid = eab.acid 
        and gam.bank_id = eab.bank_id

    left outer join tbaadm.gstt
        on gam.sol_id = gstt.sol_id 
        and gam.bank_id = gstt.bank_id
        and gam.gl_sub_head_code = gstt.gl_sub_head_code
        and gam.acct_crncy_code = gstt.crncy_code

    where 
        gam.acct_ownership = 'O' 
        --and eab.eod_date = TO_DATE('3/24/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
        and gstt.bal_date = TO_DATE('3/24/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    ) group by gstt.bal_date, totalDr, totalCr
```

can't make the bloody thing work, though. I know I'm missing something, I just can't put my finger on what it is, and where should I put it in the code. Any help would be appreciated. If you need further clarifications, just ask.

**EDIT**

I've got the code to work now, somewhat. Because there's a problem.

```
select 
    bal_date,
    gl_sub_head_code,
    sum(tot_dr_bal),
    sum(tot_cr_bal)

from( 
    select distinct 
        gam.gl_sub_head_code, 
        gstt.tot_dr_bal,
        gstt.tot_cr_bal,
        gstt.bal_date

    from tbaadm.gam

    left outer join tbaadm.eab 
        on gam.acid = eab.acid 
        and gam.bank_id = eab.bank_id

    left outer join tbaadm.gstt
        on gam.sol_id = gstt.sol_id 
        and gam.bank_id = gstt.bank_id
        and gam.gl_sub_head_code = gstt.gl_sub_head_code
        and gam.acct_crncy_code = gstt.crncy_code

    where 
        gam.acct_ownership = 'O' 
        --and eab.eod_date = TO_DATE('3/24/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
        and gstt.bal_date = TO_DATE('3/24/2014', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
    ) group by bal_date, gl_sub_head_code
```

as you can see, there is a `DISTINCT` clause at the beginning of the subquery. whenever I remove that, TOAD outputs the same set of results. I get the same results regardless if I have the `DISTINCT` clause or not. I have a feeling there's something wrong with my code, as what I'm expecting is that the `DISTINCT` should make a difference.

Comment: Why do you need to sum the amounts per GL Sub Head, when the final result is being reported per date?

Comment: You're not summing per GL Sub Head, the `DISTINCT` is just ignoring duplicates. Also, the outer query is using `bal_date`, but you're not returning that from the subquery. And you can't refer to aliases in the subquery from the outer query.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to do. Can you post some sample data and the desired output? Best would be to make a sqlfiddle that we can tweak.

Comment: I need to output the results per GL Sub Head and per date. your 2nd post, that's the bit of information I needed. However, I noticed something in the code. I'll post it as an EDIT to my original post.

Comment: You probably don't need `DISTINCT`. Do you have multiple rows with the same gl sub head and date? If you do, and they have the same amounts, do you really need to filter out the duplicates? Why are the duplicates in there in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

> "I get the same results regardless if I have the DISTINCT clause or not."

This means your query already returns a unique set of rows.

> I have a feeling there's something wrong with my code, as what I'm expecting is that the DISTINCT should make a difference.

Why do you think that?

DISTINCT made a difference in your first query because you hadn't included `bal_date` in the sub-query's projection.  So you have some `gl_sub_head` instances where the balances are the same for multiple days.

Except that you are filtering on `bal_date` so you should only get one value for it anyway. Hmmmm....

Clearly something is awry in your query.  There are two obvious puzzlers.

1. Why do you have a LEFT OUTER JOIN with `gstt`?  The hard filter on `gstt.bal_date` means you will only return records where `gstt.bal_date` is not null, so the result set would still be the same if that was an INNER JOIN.
2. Why bother querying `eab` at all?  You don't use any values from it and the LEFT OUTER JOIN means it doesn't restrict the values retrieved from `gam` in anyway.  Plus the fact that you have commented out the filter on `eab.eod_date` suggests that it currently produces a cross join which might generate multiple duplicate values which you then think you need a DISTINCT to eradicate.

So, I don't have an actual answer for you, but I think you need to re-visit your business logic and figure out what your query actually needs to do.